# How to redirect output of cowsay to be the input of zwrite

Tags: io-redirection

I run cowsay, which asks me to input text string. 
Then, it prints the result to stdout.

I want to redirect that result to zwrite instead of stdout.

The issue is that I can't do cowsay  | zwrite
because after I run cowsay, it runs in REPL asking me to input the argv , then it prints the result to stdout. In this case, I can't think of a way to redirect its output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
echo "some text"|cowsay
```

To redirect the output of cowsay you can use:

```
echo "some text"|cowsay > /tmp/cowsay.out
```

or

```
echo "some text"|cowsay|zwrite user
```